# Simple, open source aerodynamics simulation software that can import Blender or Sketchup models?

Tags: open-source, simulation

What are some basic, open source aerodynamics or computational fluid dynamics (CFD) simulation software that can import Blender or Sketchup models? I am looking for software that is easy-to-use, free, and suitable for educational purposes.

Comment: Blender has something like that built-in. I guess that's not "simple enough", right? Do you know a commercial application that is close to what you're looking for?

Comment: @Thomas It does? What's it called?

Comment: I don't know exactly, since I never used it myself. Just read about it. Fluids: https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.4/Manual/Physics/Fluid Smoke (to visualize aerodynamics): https://www.blender.org/manual/de/physics/smoke/types/flow_object.html

Comment: @Thomas interesting: "The algorithm used for Blender’s fluid simulation is the Lattice Boltzmann Method (LBM); other fluid algorithms include Navier-Stokes (NS) solvers and Smoothed Particle Hydrodynamics (SPH) methods. LBM lies somewhere between these two."